# How to seed PRNG for usage with BN_rand*?

Tags: c, openssl

I would like to use:

```
BN_rand_range(...);
```

and due to the OpenSSL documentation:

> The PRNG must be seeded prior to calling BN_rand() or BN_rand_range().

But there is no link or method name hint provided how I could do that. What is the correct way to seed the PRNG with OpenSSL?

Comment: `BN_init(ref)` or `BN_new()` is required to create a new `BIGNUM`. Don't guess they would call it `seed the PRNG`. I guess there is some `*_seed*` function available. In fact if found multiple ones in the OpenSSL package, but don't have any idea which one I need.

Comment: It looks to me like they're telling you that beforee you call BN_rand_range() you should make sure that RAND_status() returns 1; according to https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#USER1 it looks like openssl tries to seed itself using the OS equivalent of /dev/urandom, but I've never really tried.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7718/openssl-rand-poll-good-enough

Comment: @loreb Your second links seems useless for me, but `RAND_status()` seems a good tipp. Guess this link about `RAND_status()` explains it very well: http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to seed the PRNG with OpenSSL?

Internally, OpenSSL of auto-seeds itself with `RAND_poll` (with some hand waiving). There's a few reasons why you might want to avoid the behavior and explicitly seed the generator yourself.

There's a more complete writeup on the OpenSSL wiki at [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers).